# Win32 CreateWindow() error, this is nullptr

Tags: c++, winapi, nullptr, createwindow

I'm creating a child window in another class, so I pass the hWnd and the hInstance of the parent into the function, where I'm creating the child window.

My problem now is, that the createWindow() function of the child window hangs up and I get an error message which says: "An exception has beend encountered. This may be caused by an extension".

Does someone know what this message means, or what I'm doing wrong?

Here is it, where I'm calling the child window in the message handler of the parent window, because I'm using a submenu with ID's.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK System::MessageHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    MainMenu mMainMenu;

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch (LOWORD(wparam))
            {
                //If user presses on the exit button
                case IDM_FILE_EXIT:
                {
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                } break;

                case IDM_NEW_NEWPROJECT:
                {
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////
                    // Here is the error showing up
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////
                    m_CreateProjectMenu->Initialize(m_hWnd, m_hinstance);
                }break;


                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Any other messages send to the default message handler as our application won't make use of them.
        default:
        {
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam);
        }
    }
}
```

Initialize:

```
bool CreateProjectMenu::Initialize(HWND m_ParentWindow, HINSTANCE m_hParentInstance)
{
    //Initialize the window
    InitializeWindow(m_ParentWindow, m_hParentInstance);

    return true;
}
```

InitializeWindow:

```
void CreateProjectMenu::InitializeWindow(HWND m_ParentWindow, HINSTANCE m_hParentInstance)
{
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;                 // Defines additional elements of the window class.
    wc.lpfnWndProc = ChildProc;                         // A pointer to the window procedure.
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;                                  // The number of extra bytes to allocate following the window-class structure.
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;                                  // The number of extra bytes to allocate following the window instance.
    wc.hInstance = m_hParentInstance;                   // A handle to the instance that contains the window procedure.
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(wc.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION); // Load the icon for the application.
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);           // Load the cursor for the application.
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);      // Load the background for the application.
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;                             // Pointer to a character string that specifies the name of the resource class menu.
    wc.lpszClassName = m_ProjectMenuWindowName;         // Set the name for the window.
    wc.hInstance = m_hParentInstance;

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to register the menuprojectwindow", L"Error", MB_OK);
    }

    m_NewProjectHwnd = CreateWindow(NULL,
        m_ProjectMenuWindowName,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION
        | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
        | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        screenWidth, screenHeight,
        m_ParentWindow,
        NULL,
        m_hParentInstance,
        NULL);

    // Check if the hwnd is zero(error)
    // Display a messagebox with a error
    if (m_NewProjectHwnd == 0)
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not create the create project hwnd.", L"Error", MB_OK);    
    else
    {
        ShowWindow(m_NewProjectHwnd, SW_SHOW);  // Bring the window up on the screen
        SetFocus(m_NewProjectHwnd);
    }

    return;
}
```

Here is the code to reproduce the error:
https://ufile.io/ddmj4

Comment: The error message you've posted is caused by Visual Studio error. The code seems to be ok. And it is not clear how "this is nullptr" related to the question content. Where exactly `this` is  a `nullptr`?

Comment: The visual studio error is showing up, when I call the initializeWindow function in the parentmessagehandler, and I really don't know why because this never happened to me so I can't figure out, what is causing the problem.I also searched the web for such an error, but it seems that no one had this yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`this` is the implicit first argument of every non-static class method. It is a pointer to the object on which the method is called. The error message you are getting means you have called a method on a `nullptr`. Though your code is incomplete, the only line where this could happen is

```
m_CreateProjectMenu->Initialize(m_hWnd, m_hinstance);
```

You can verify this by using a debugger to check `m_CreatePorjectMenu`'s value right before the call is made, or by adding an `assert(CreatePorjectMenu);`. For the latter, make sure you are compiling with assertions enabled.

As for how to solve it, I can't tell without knowing your project's structure. Some function must have the responsibility to initialize that object and you have to make sure it is called before your callback. Alternatively, if the initializer pattern doesn't work for whatever reason, your callback can check for `nullptr` and create the object if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation about what the error could be. I tried the debugger right before the call and  he is unable to read the memory. And I can verify it with the assert(CreateProjectMenu), it already throws me out there and returns a nullptr. PS: I made a link where I pasted the code to recreate the problem, maybe you have to delete some unnecessary code, but I hope not.

Comment: The [mcve] needs to be posted *in the question*, not just a link to .zip file.  But the most common mistake leading to this scenario would be initializing `m_CreateProjectMenu` *after* the call to CreateWindow, perhaps under the mistaken impression that you wouldn't get any window messages until you started your message pump.